# django view error: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to create a view to update a model. The model has a ManyToMany relationship. I use a ModelMultipleChoiceField in the form which queries the m2m table for a list of values. I want to be able to update/change the m2m attributes on the record when the record is updated. When I submit this form (update), I get

more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

I expect there to be more than one value, but my code isn't handling it.

Thanks for your help.

**Models.py**

```
class Activities(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.link.url)

class Groups (models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    activity = models.ManyToManyField(Activities)
    active_yn = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.group

class ActivitiesForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Activities

class GroupsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Groups
```

**forms.py**
(I think the issue is here: group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(**queryset=Groups.objects.all()**,

```
#Add/Replace data in Activity Save
    # radio buttons
choices = ( (1,'Yes'),(0,'No'),
          )



# activity groups
class ActivitySaveForm(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField(
        label=u'URL',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 64})
    )
    name = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Activity Name',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 64})
    )  
    desc = forms.CharField(
        label=u'Describe it',
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 250})
    )
    group = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Groups.objects.all(), required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
    done = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
    )
```

**views.py**
a secondary question is: How do I use something other than Groups.objects.get_or_create(**id=group**) if I don't want to return the id but want to return a different value in the model (Groups.group).

```
def activity_save_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ActivitySaveForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            url, dummy = Link.objects.get_or_create(
                url=form.cleaned_data['url']
            )   
            act, created = Activities.objects.get_or_create(
                user=request.user,
                url=url
            )                                              
            act.desc = form.cleaned_data['desc']
            if not created:
                act.groups_set.clear()
            group = form.cleaned_data['group']
            for groups in group:
                group, dummy = Groups.objects.get_or_create(id=group)
                act.groups_set_add(group)
            act.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                '/user/%s/' % request.user.username
            )
    else:
        form = ActivitySaveForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form
    })
    return render_to_response('activity_save.html', variables)
```

Finally, the traceback if you need it.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/activity_save/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'poc.location',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'south']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/footbook/webapps/fb/poc/../poc/location/views.py" in activity_save_page
  327.                 group, dummy = Groups.objects.get_or_create(id=group)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get_or_create
  135.         return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get_or_create
  378.             return self.get(**lookup), False
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  344.         num = len(clone)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  82.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  273.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  680.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  735.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py" in execute
  44.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /activity_save/
Exception Value: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I think I have the wrong method to get the data, but not sure what I should be using. There is a ton of info on this error, but I couldn't find a solution that fit this need. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback says the problem is here:

```
File "/home/footbook/webapps/fb/poc/../poc/location/views.py" in activity_save_page
327. group, dummy = Groups.objects.get_or_create(id=group)
```

I think the problem is you're using 'group' and 'groups' in a confusing way. You don't ever actually use 'groups' anywhere

```
group = form.cleaned_data['group'] <--- first you set group to a list from your form
for groups in group: <--- then you use 'groups' to indicate *one* group from the list
    group, dummy = Groups.objects.get_or_create(id=group) <-- then you assign the list to the 'id' parameter.
```

Did you mean this:

```
groups = form.cleaned_data['group']
for group in groups:
    this_group, dummy = Groups.objects.get_or_create(id=group)
    # do something with this_group
```

Without looking more closely at your code, I don't know if this will actually work for what you're doing or not.

Comment: Thanks alan - that was exactly it. I changed some names to avoid the confusion and was able to work it out.

Comment: @jabs: Great. Glad I could help. You might want to accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks.